# The Joukowski Mapping circle unit mapping to elipse

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let's say we have a following function:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$$ Find the image of a $B(\sqrt{2}i,1)$, when mapped by given function.

My results:

$f(z) = \frac{1}{2}(z + \frac{1}{z}) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{(z|z|^{2}+\overline z)}{|z|^{2}} = \frac{1}{2} (z + \frac{\overline z}{|z|^{2}}) $

So I prepared simple, when $B(0,1)$ I computed the result $[-1,1]$

Because we have: 
$z \in B(0,1) $ is represented by $z = e^{i\alpha}$

so using the equation $$w = \frac{1}{2}(e^{i\alpha} + e^{- i\alpha})$$ it is $\cos(\alpha)$
so the value of $\cos$ is in $[-1,1]$

How to prove that the image of $B(\sqrt{2}i,1)$ is like lower?

[image]

edit:

parametric plot for $2 (x^{2} + y^{2})^{2} == 2 y^{2} + x^{2}$

edit2:
$$u+vi = f(z) $$
$(u,v)$ in ${\mathbb C} - [-1,1]$ I prepered $$z=re^{i\alpha}$$ $r < 1$ such that $${\displaystyle \bigg({u \over (r + {1 \over r})}\bigg)^2 + \bigg({v \over (r - {1 \over r})}\bigg)^2 = {1 \over 4}}$$ so it's an elipse.

Why my image of $B(\sqrt2i,1)$ looks like the half eclipse?

I show that the foci are the points $(-1,0) , (1,0)$

[image]

Comment: Is $B(\sqrt 2 i,1)$ the circle with center at $\sqrt 2 i$ and radius $1$? Then your figure is wrong. The blue circle could not touch the $x$ axis.

Comment: @Andrei yes. The figure has the same interpretation

Comment: for $B(\sqrt 2 i,1)$ you have $z=e^{i\phi}+i\sqrt 2$. The exponential term is $B(0,1)$, and you just need to shift the center. The rest is just arithmetic

Comment: The disk $B(i \sqrt 2, 1)$ is mapped to the interior of the curve $2 (x^2 + y^2)^2 = x^2 + 2 y^2$. The curve is orthogonal to the $x$-axis because the circle $C(i \sqrt 2, 1)$ is orthogonal to $C(0, 1)$.

Comment: @Maxim I am not sure about your suggestion, look on my edit.

Comment: @Andrei I am not sure how it's not simple arithmetic. My results show that image is eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B(0,1)$ means $z=e^{i\phi}$. Changing the center to $\sqrt 2 i$ means you just need to add this value to $z$, so $$z=e^{i\phi}+\sqrt 2 i$$
Then $$\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac 12(e^{i\phi}+\sqrt 2 i+\frac 1{e^{i\phi}+\sqrt 2 i})\\ &=\frac 12(e^{i\phi}+\sqrt 2 i+\frac {e^{-i\phi}-\sqrt 2 i}{(e^{i\phi}+\sqrt 2 i)({e^{-i\phi}-\sqrt 2 i})})\\&=\frac 12(e^{i\phi}+\sqrt 2 i+\frac {e^{-i\phi}-\sqrt 2 i}{3+2\sqrt2\sin\phi})\\&=\frac{\cos\phi}{2}(1+\frac 1{3+2\sqrt2\sin\phi})+\frac{\sin\phi+\sqrt 2}{2}(1-\frac 1{3+2\sqrt 2\sin\phi})i\end{align}$$

Comment: $3 + 2 \sin \phi$ in the denominator should be $3 + 2 \sqrt 2 \sin \phi$.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks. I'll fix it now